# Rudins introduction, no largest element in {$p \in \mathbb{Q} | p^2<2$}

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

Small question, what other values would work instead of $p+2$ in
$$q=p-\frac{p^2-2}{p+2}$$?

Edit:
Here is the snippet from the book:
[image]

Comment: "work" to do *what*??

Comment: @coffeemath, to find  $q$, s.t. $q$ is larger than $p$ and $q^2 < 2$

Comment: What does $^2 2$ mean in displayed line (4)?

Comment: @coffeemath, sadly, I am not sure myself, I think its just a typo, because it would not be the first, and because of a lecture which is based on this chapter, this topic was covered and everything was as if this {2}^2 is just a 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to show that the rationals can be split into two groups, where one has no least upper bound and the other has no greatest lower bound.

If $A: \{p \in \Bbb{Q} : p^2<2\}$ and $B: \{p \in \Bbb{Q} : p^2>2\}$, the goal is to show that for any $x \in A, \exists y \in A$ such that $x<y$.

Similarly, for any $x \in B, \exists y \in B$ such that $y<x$. In other words, there is always another rational number between the one you selected and $\sqrt 2$.

I will show the work for (3):

$q = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{p+2} = \frac{p(p+2)-(p^2 - 2)}{p+2} = \frac{2p+2}{p+2}$. Note that for $q = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{p+b} = \frac{bp+2}{p+b}$.

So now let some $p \in A$. By the way $A$ was defined, $p^2 - 2 < 0$, so

$q = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{p+2} > p.$ But is $q$ also an element of A? This is where that $p + 2$ is important.

Okay, so $q \in A$ if $q^2 - 2 < 0$. So let's see what happens when we take $q^2 - 2$:

$q^2 - 2 = (\frac{2p + 2}{p+2})^2 - 2 = \frac{4p^2 + 8p + 4}{(p+2)^2} - \frac{2(p+2)^2}{(p+2)^2} = \frac{2p^2 - 4}{(p+2)^2} = \frac{2(p^2 - 2)}{(p+2)^2}$.

But wait a minute! We already showed $q > p$. But also notice that if $p \in A$, $\frac{2(p^2 - 2)}{(p+2)^2} < 0$. So then $q^2 - 2 < 0$, implying that $q^2 < 2.$ By the definition of $A, q \in A$.

As an exercise, try it with some other denominator like $p + 1$.